# Is there something wrong with this usage of 'letting someone into a secret'?

Tags: idioms

Recently I had to write somewhere and this phrase made good sense except I am not too sure about the usage?

**Let me in you on a secret** (followed by the secret)

Is this correct? If not what can I write here alternatively using the same phrase?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You appear to be trying to make a single instance of *let* express two different meanings:

- *Let me VERB* means (approximately) "permit me to VERB":

  > Let me tell you a secret. = "Permit me to tell you a secret".

  It's employed in the imperative to add a little courtesy to the announcement that you are going to *VERB*.
- *Let you in on X* is an idiom meaning "reveal X to you":

  > I'm going to let you in on a secret. = "I'm going to tell you a secret".

If you want to include both of these notions you must either include the verb *let* twice (which is awkward) or paraphrase one instance:

> <sup>AWK</sup>Let me let you in on a secret.
>   <sup>OK</sup>Let me tell you a secret.

Comment: Or _Allow me to let you in on a secret._

Comment: another commonly used alternative is "to share a secret" . "I'll share a secret with you" or simply "I want to share a secret" ("with you" can go without saying when using 'share' and addressing someone)